# Possible to embed html in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to embed html within javascript? I am trying to pass two different forms based on the input to a radio button. My question is this possible?

```
<script>
if(document.getElementById('hello').checked) {
    <p> form 1 </p>
}else if(document.getElementById('goodbye').checked) {
  <p> form 2</p>
}
</script>
<button onclick="">one or the other</button>
```

Comment: What should in general `<p> form 1 </p>` be?!

Comment: What should do that `<button onclick="">one or the other</button>`?

Comment: ideally, that would display a text based form: 
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: and if the other radio check box is clicked then a different form would be displayed.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to have a "visible" and "invisible" class to attach to the forms, while just having both form templates written out in the html. And if the radio button for form1 is clicked, just add the "visible" class to that form1 element, while adding the "invisible" class to the form2 element. And vice versa. The visible and invisible classes could have styles defined which display them and hides them, respectively.

Comment: thank you for your insight -- I was not aware of the visible and invisible classes. That sounds easy enough to implement. I will give it a try! thank you again!

Comment: @lizzo for clarity, you will need to create those classes, something as simple as `.visible { display: block } .invisible { display: none }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an Object with templates forms.
Depending on the `checked` radio element, you simply reference the template by the checked radio element `value`:

```js
const form_templates = {
  contact: `<form action="/form_contact.php">
<label><span>First name:</span><input type="text" name="fname"></label>
<label><span>Last name:</span><input type="text" name="lname"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`,
  newsletter: `<form action="/newsletter.php">
<label><span>Email:</span><input type="text" name="email"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`
};

const ELS_picker = document.querySelectorAll("[name=form-picker]"); 
const EL_picked = document.querySelector("#picked"); 

const pickForm = () => {
  const ckd = [...ELS_picker].filter(el => el.checked)[0];
  EL_picked.innerHTML = form_templates[ckd.value];
};


//  On radio change
ELS_picker.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", pickForm));
// Init!
pickForm();
```

```html
<h3>Select a form:</h3>
<label>Contact: <input type="radio" value="contact" name="form-picker" checked></label>
<label>Newsletter: <input type="radio" value="newsletter" name="form-picker"></label>

<div id="picked"></div>
```

Example with two forms already defined in the document and by using [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
const ELS_picker = document.querySelectorAll("[name=form-picker]");

const pickForm = () => {
  const ckd = ELS_picker.forEach(el => {
    document.querySelector(`[id="form--${el.value}"]`).classList.toggle("u-none", !el.checked);
  });
};

//  On radio change
ELS_picker.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", pickForm));

// Init!
pickForm();
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Select a form:</h3>
<label>Contact: <input type="radio" value="contact" name="form-picker" checked></label>
<label>Newsletter: <input type="radio" value="newsletter" name="form-picker"></label>

<form id="form--contact" class="u-none" action="/form_contact.php">
  <label><span>First name:</span><input type="text" name="fname"></label>
  <label><span>Last name:</span><input type="text" name="lname"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form--newsletter" class="u-none" action="/newsletter.php">
  <label><span>Email:</span><input type="text" name="email"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you!

Comment: ,are you wrapping the constant variables in <script> tags in the html documents? Where are you writing that section of code?

const ELS_picker = document.querySelectorAll("[name=form-picker]");

const pickForm = () => {
  const ckd = ELS_picker.forEach(el => {
    document.querySelector(`[id="form--${el.value}"]`).classList.toggle("u-none", !el.checked);
  });
};

//  On radio change
ELS_picker.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", pickForm));

// Init!
pickForm();

* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;  # this looks like inline css, right?
}

Comment: @lizzo All JavaScript should go in `<script>` tags right **before(!)** the closing **body** tag: `<!-- JS GOES HERE!!! --> </body>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you may have to inject like this:

```html
<div id="form"></div>
<button onclick="">one or the other</button>
<script>
var formEl = document.getElementById('form');
if(document.getElementById('hello').checked) {
  formEl.innerHTML = '<p> form 1 </p>';
}else if(document.getElementById('goodbye').checked) {
  formEl.innerHTML = '<p> form 2</p>';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to update the HTML on your JS code, you should use functions like `document.createElement`.

Check the section `Creating and placing new nodes` [at this Mozilla's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).